# How to store additional data in a listbox?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a wpf application using Caliburn.Micro. I need to bind a ListBox to a collection of objects, but I want to display one of the object's fields, and also somehow to attach a Guid (another field) to each item. Could you please tell me how I can do that? I don't know if Caliburn.Micro has something specific for it, or I just have to use WPF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

If the Guid field is part of your object, you do not need to store it on another place. The listbox will show a field but it is still bounded to the original object, you can get it with `((MyObjectType)MyListBox.SelectedItem).Guid`. With Caliburn it is even easier since you just need to bind a property on your VM to SelectedItem.

But if the Guid **is not** part of your object, you can use the Tag property, as Paul Sasik said. I do not like to use the Tag property so this is another easy (and more flexbible) way you can solve this, you need to encapsulate your object on another object:

```
public class GuidObject<T>
{
    public T Instance {get;set;}
    public Guid Guid {get;set;}
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
//this is your original guidless items list
var myObjectsList = new[] { new MyObject { Name = "Dostoyevsky" }, 
                            new MyObject { Name = "Ozzy" } };

var myObjectsWithGuidList = new ObservableCollection<GuidObject<MyObject>>();

//encapsulate each MyObject on a GuidObject and include a Guid
//if your myObjectsList is already a List, you do not need to call ToList()
myObjectsList.ToList().ForEach(o => myObjectsWithGuidList.Add(new GuidObject<MyObject>() { Instance = o, Guid = Guid.NewGuid() }));

//now myObjectsWithGuidList contains a list of your itens and a Guid field, you can bind it to your ListBox
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/KPN63206) you can see this running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) of each ListBox object to store arbitrary information.

From the link:

> This property is analogous to Tag properties in other Microsoft
>   programming models, such as Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
>   (VBA) or Windows Forms. Tag is intended to provide a pre-existing
>   property location where you can store some basic custom information
>   about any FrameworkElement without requiring you to subclass an
>   element.
>
> Because this property takes an object, you would need to use the
>   property element usage in order to set the Tag property in Extensible
>   Application Markup Language (XAML) to anything other than an object
>   with a known and built-in type converter, such as a string. Objects
>   used in this manner are typically not within the standard Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF) namespaces and therefore may require
>   namespace mapping to the external namespace in order to be introduced
>   as XAML elements.